# User List not showing on Spring Boot - error findAll () or thymeleaf

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{fragments/main_layout}">
<head>
    <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div layout:fragment="content" class="container mySpace">
    <form action="/users" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Search User" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search"  class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Add</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="user:${users}">
                    <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
                    <td><a  th:href="@{/addTask(email=${user.email})}" class="btn btn-dark">AddTask</a></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

list.html

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.services;

import com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.Role;
import com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.User;
import com.loginregister.loginregister.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.management.Query;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public List<User> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.contollers;

import com.loginregister.loginregister.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String listUsers(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findAll());
        return "views/list";
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.repositories;

import com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

}
```

UserRepository.java

user list not showing. I wonder where I am doing wrong. He was working with another friend. I do not understand from Spring Boot versions or from thymeleaf

```
<tbody>
                <tr th:each="user:${users}">
                    <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
                    <td><a  th:href="@{/addTask(email=${user.email})}" class="btn btn-dark">AddTask</a></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
```

i think, this section needs something to for work with

User List now showing on Spring Boot - error findAll () or thymeleaf

Comment: Your model is named `user` not `users`. `model.addAttribute("user", userService.findAll());` should be `model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());`

Comment: yess, thanks so much